# How to get PC of first instruction of inline asm block (C)?

Tags: c, assembly, microcontroller, inline-assembly, riscv

I am writing code for a RISCV microcontroller.
I am searching for a trick to get the program counter (PC) of an extended inline asm block, from a file different from the inline asm itself. Note: this asm block is not the initial code in a function.

The reason is that the hardware will trigger some side effects when (or if) the execution reaches that specific PC.

A pseudo-C solution can be the following (the code won't work ofc).

File_A.c

```
//some_code
chat routine_name[10] = 'routine';
uint32_t routine_start_PC = get_start_PC(routine_name);
// some_other_code
```

File_B.c

```
void foo_rou(){
   //some_code_BEFORE (IMPORTANT!)
   routine:
   asm volatile(
   ...
   );
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Just sticking your label into the inline asm, along with a `.global` should do it.

Comment: Then declare the label in C like `extern char your_label[];`. You can get the address by `(uintptr_t)your_label`.

Comment: I tried but without success, can you explain me better?
I am trying in a single file first: 
`void* routine_PC = &&routine`
and later below inside the `asm volatile` I have `".global routine:"` but I am getting already here "routine used but not defined"

Answer (score 3):

This is my suggestion on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z87oG8z8v):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void routine(void);

void foo_rou(void) {
    printf("Begin of %s()\n", __FUNCTION__);
    asm volatile(
        ".global routine\n"
        "routine:"
    );
    printf("End of %s()\n", __FUNCTION__);
}

void print_ptr(void *p) {
    printf("%p\n", p);
}

int main(void) {
    print_ptr((void*)foo_rou);
    print_ptr((void*)routine);
}
```

It uses the separate function `print_ptr()` to identify the actual addresses.

The assembly listing shows that `routine` is handled correctly:

```
main:
 addi   sp,sp,-16
 sd s0,0(sp)
 lui    a1,0x10
 lui    s0,0x10
 addi   a1,a1,1394 # 10572 <foo_rou>
 addi   a0,s0,1488 # 105d0 <_IO_stdin_used+0x28>
 sd ra,8(sp)
 jal    ra,104a0 <printf@plt>
 lui    a1,0x10
 addi   a0,s0,1488
 addi   a1,a1,1414 # 10586 <routine>
 jal    ra,104a0 <printf@plt>
 ld ra,8(sp)
 ld s0,0(sp)
 li a0,0
 addi   sp,sp,16
 ret
 ...
load_gp:
 auipc  gp,0x2
 addi   gp,gp,766 # 12800 <__global_pointer$>
 ret
 ...
foo_rou: # [my addition] 0x10572
 addi   sp,sp,-16
 sd s0,0(sp)
 lui    a0,0x10
 addi   a1,gp,-2000 # 12030 <__FUNCTION__.0>
 addi   a0,a0,1456 # 105b0 <_IO_stdin_used+0x8>
 sd ra,8(sp)
 jal    ra,104a0 <printf@plt>
routine: # [my addition] 0x10586
 addi   a1,gp,-2000 # 12030 <__FUNCTION__.0>
 ld s0,0(sp)
 ld ra,8(sp)
 lui    a0,0x10
 addi   a0,a0,1472 # 105c0 <_IO_stdin_used+0x18>
 addi   sp,sp,16
 j  104a0 <printf@plt>
print_ptr:
 mv a1,a0
 lui    a0,0x10
 addi   a0,a0,1488 # 105d0 <_IO_stdin_used+0x28>
 j  104a0 <printf@plt>
```

The important part is the declaration of the function `routine`. This lets the compiler know that there is a function of that name, so you can reference it. General advice: Don't do anything else with it.

You can declare the prototype with a parameter list and return type, and call it from C, as long as the ABI is met. (*WARNING: Do so only if you exactly know what you are doing. It is very brittle! The smallest change of your source or compile options can break it.*)

Since such a declaration has no definition, you define the symbol as shown in the inline assembler part.

Please note that some compilers add an underscore as a prefix to C symbols. For such compilers you will need to use `_routine`.

Comment: Beware that if you put a `ret` into that asm statement, calling `foo_rou` is no longer safe.  And if you don't, it's definitely not safe to call `routine` from C.  Calling into the middle of a C function and having execution come out the bottom without having gone in the top is not something GCC supports. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels  (In practice, the `foo_rou` prologue won't have run, so its epilogue will make a mess.  Especially since its a non-leaf function with the call to `printf` still there, so it'll be restoring a return address from the stack.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure. That's what I mean by "_the ABI is met._" If one writes hacky code, commonly the support of the compiler ends.

Comment: "The ABI" normally refers to the standard calling convention, like what the caller will expect if you call `routine()` from C.  That's a different thing from having execution enter the `asm` statement as part of running the `foo_rou` function, where the interface between compiler and hand-written asm is defined by the operand and clobber constraints of the extended-asm statement, and the semantics of that.

Comment: The term ABI doesn't fit because it's not a *binary* interface; asm text substitution of operands in the template can still happen, and it's not a calling convention because it doesn't return, execution comes out the bottom.  (And if it doesn't, it's a lot harder to keep the compiler happy.)  There's definitely no standard location where an `asm` statement can expect to find the function's return address, and there might not be one if this function inlined into its caller.

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh, I'm quite sure that "ABI" points the right direction. It is not generally portable, of course. If I add the code to finish and quit the C function after the first part, and after the label similarly add the code of the start of the function, the resulting machine code is equal to the one generated from two separate functions. The inline assembly part allows me anything.

Comment: How could that possibly work?  There isn't one boilerplate prologue block that can start any function; the amount of stack space reserved, and which call-preserved registers saved where in the stack can differ.  Depending on optimization level and which compiler / version you use, different builds of the same source code can come out differently.  `foo_rou` isn't declared `__attribute__((noinline))` so could even inline into its caller such that there is no return address for `foo_rou`.  The OP specified "some code", not necessarily just a `printf()` with no local vars.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yeah, we don't know what the OP targets. It can be anything. As I said, it is not portable, this includes compiling with the same compiler but different options. Such hacks are very brittle and not for beginners. Let's stop this discussion, please, it leads nowhere. I'll add a warning.